# How to display name of customer with maximum no. of orders in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How to display name of customer with maximum no. of orders in MongoDB? Orders are a nested subdocument.

{

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5bd729c463b37537e42174a3"),
"name" : "Vedang",
"no" : "123",
"city" : "Pune",
"orders" : [
    {
        "order" : "1",
        "type" : "clothes",
        "total" : "1000"
    },
    {
        "order" : "2",
        "type" : "clothes",
        "total" : "2000"
    },
    {
        "order" : "3",
        "type" : "shoes",
        "total" : "3000"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation framework.

Use `$size` to get the orders array length followed by `$sort` desc and `$facet` to output the max order size and all the documents with their count and name.

`$project` with `$filter` to output all the docs with count matching with max order count.

`$unwind` with `$project` to output the name of the highest orders.

Something like

```
db.colname.aggregate([
 {"$addFields":{"ordersize":{"$size":"$orders"}}},
 {"$sort":{"ordersize":-1}},
 {"$facet":{"maxordersize":[{"$limit":1},{"$project":{"ordersize":1}}], "docs":[{"$project":{"ordersize":1, "name":"$name"}}]}},
 {"$project":{"docs":{"$filter":{"input":"$docs","cond":{"$eq":["$$this.ordersize",{"$arrayElemAt":["$maxordersize.ordersize", 0]]}}}}}},
 {"$unwind":"$docs"},
 {"$project":{"name":"$docs.name"}}
])
```

Comment: What if there are multiple entries with the same number of orders? That is an issue I am facing

Comment: What do you want to do ? List them all ?

Comment: I want to list all the customers with maximum no. of orders. In this case, the no. of orders is 3 and there could be multiple such customers with three orders. I want to display them all.

Comment: Updated answer. Please give it a try.